# How to get an onCompletion handler from other class?

Tags: android, class, listeners

Another silly question from this Android newbie, please be patient with me... :)

I've a class called Music that loads/plays music:

```
public class Music implements OnCompletionListener{
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
...
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
...
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) { ... }
...
}
```

Then, I have another class called MainClass, with the UI, that loads a Music with

```
Music track = Music(fileDescriptor);
```

Now, what I want is to do something in the UI (MainClass) when track ends playing or is stopped. But the MediaPlayer is inside Music, not inside MainClass, as well as setOnCompletionListener and the onCompletion method.

So, how MainClass knows that music has ended playing??

Thanks!
L.

Comment: You could implement the `OnCompletionListener` in your main class, and set `setOnCompletionListener` to your main class.

Comment: My MainClass actually extends Activity: "public class MainClass extends Activity {...}". Tried to add OnCompletionListener by writing "public class OpenBird implements OnCompletionListener extends Activity {...}" and importing OnCompletionListener but got many many errors. The implementation should not go in the class constructor? Sorry...

Comment: Yes, it worked!! Thanks Bob! In case someone needs it, I did in my MainClass: `public class MainClass extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener {...`, implemented the "onCompletion" method, and `track.mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);` (notice the `.mediaPlayer`). Thanks again!