# onCompletion Listener for between switches

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I've got an issue which I think I can see the solution to but I just can't work out how to implement it. I'm quite new to this whole game.

I'm building an app which will "read" any number which is entered into it. So far I've got the app to take an inputed number and turn it into a 4 digit string which is then added to an array. The plan is to use this to run switch events for each digit, so if the first digit is 1 it will play the "one" sound clip followed by the "thousand" sound clip. I've got this bit working but when I try to get the second digit to run through a switch (e.g. "one" followed by "hundred") I just get the second lot of sound clips playing over the first. What I need to do is get the onCompletionListener working between these two switches; I've seen this question which seems to be asking the same thing but I can't work out how to use the answer...

[How to get an onCompletion handler from other class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059997/how-to-get-an-oncompletion-handler-from-other-class)

Here is my code if you want to see what I've been doing.

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Number_Reader extends Activity {

TextView readNumberTV;
TextView numberLengthTV;
int currentLength;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_number__reader);

    readNumberTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.read_input);
    numberLengthTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_length);

}

public void btn_zero_click(View view) {
    add("0");}
public void btn_one_click(View view) {
    add("1");}
public void btn_two_click(View view) {
    add("2");}
public void btn_three_click(View view) {
    add("3");}
public void btn_four_click(View view) {
    add("4");}
public void btn_five_click(View view) {
    add("5");}
public void btn_six_click(View view) {
    add("6");}
public void btn_seven_click(View view) {
    add("7");}
public void btn_eight_click(View view) {
    add("8");}
public void btn_nine_click(View view) {
    add("9");}

public void add(String num)
{
    currentLength++;
    readNumberTV.append(num);
}

public void onSendRead(View view) {

    MediaPlayer one = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.one);
    MediaPlayer two = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.two);
    MediaPlayer three = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.three);
    MediaPlayer four = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.four);
    MediaPlayer five = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.five);
    MediaPlayer six = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.six);
    MediaPlayer seven = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.seven);
    MediaPlayer eight = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.eight);
    MediaPlayer nine = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.nine);

    int n = Integer.parseInt(readNumberTV.getText().toString());

    String newNumber = String.format("%04d", n);

    char[] digits = newNumber.toCharArray();

    String str1 = digits[0] + "";
    String str2 = digits[1] + "";
    String str3 = digits[2] + "";
    String str4 = digits[3] + "";

    int foo1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
    int foo2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);
    int foo3 = Integer.parseInt(str3);
    int foo4 = Integer.parseInt(str4);

    switch (foo1) {
        case 1:
            one.start();
            one.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                MediaPlayer thousand = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.thousand);
                    thousand.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            two.start();
            two.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                MediaPlayer thousand = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.thousand);
                    thousand.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 3:
            three.start();
            three.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                MediaPlayer thousand = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.thousand);
                    thousand.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 4:
            four.start();
            four.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                MediaPlayer thousand = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.thousand);
                    thousand.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 5:
            five.start();
            five.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                MediaPlayer thousand = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.thousand);
                    thousand.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 6:
            six.start();
            six.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                MediaPlayer thousand = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.thousand);
                    thousand.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 7:
            seven.start();
            seven.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                MediaPlayer thousand = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.thousand);
                    thousand.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 8:
            eight.start();
            eight.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                MediaPlayer thousand = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.thousand);
                    thousand.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 9:
            nine.start();
            nine.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                MediaPlayer thousand = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.thousand);
                    thousand.start();
                }
            });
            break;

    }

    switch (foo2) {
        case 1:
            one.start();
            one.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    MediaPlayer hundred = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.hundred);
                    hundred.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            two.start();
            two.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    MediaPlayer hundred = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.hundred);
                    hundred.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 3:
            three.start();
            three.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    MediaPlayer hundred = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.hundred);
                    hundred.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 4:
            four.start();
            four.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    MediaPlayer hundred = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.hundred);
                    hundred.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 5:
            five.start();
            five.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    MediaPlayer hundred = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.hundred);
                    hundred.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 6:
            six.start();
            six.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    MediaPlayer hundred = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.hundred);
                    hundred.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 7:
            seven.start();
            seven.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    MediaPlayer hundred = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.hundred);
                    hundred.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 8:
            eight.start();
            eight.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    MediaPlayer hundred = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.hundred);
                    hundred.start();
                }
            });
            break;
        case 9:
            nine.start();
            nine.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    MediaPlayer hundred = MediaPlayer.create(Number_Reader.this, R.raw.hundred);
                    hundred.start();
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}



public void onSendClear(View view) {
    readNumberTV.setText(null);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

This might not be the best way of doing this (in fact it probably isn't) if anyone has any advice on this I like to hear it.

Also I'm pretty sure I've not got the most concise code (at this point I'm just happy if it works) if anyone wants to give any pointers on that I'd appreciate it too.

Sorry this is a bit wordy but I wanted to make sure I was being clear.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you want to hear

"One Thouse One Hunded Ninty Three"

But right now you're hearing all of those words on top of each other, broken up by which switch their in?  I.E One thousand is played in order, and One Hundred is played in order, but the two sets are played simultaneously?

Comment: That's it. The onComplition listeners are working for the two switches I just need to start one after the other is finished playing.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a recursive function, the problem can be solved because the announcement of one number occurs only after the previous ones are finished. The method below can be used-

```
  private void announceNumber(int input){
      int numberOfDigits = countNumberOfDigits(input);
      if(numberOfDigits>1){
        int currentDigitToBeAnnounced = (input/Math.pow(10,(numberOfDigits-1)));
        int nexIterationNumber = (input%Math.pow(numberOfDigits-1));
        // The next two announce calls can be synchronized by putting them
        // in the same method
        announcedCurrentNumber(currentDigitToBeAnnounced);
        announceMultiplier(numberOfDigits);
        // make the recursive call made here in the method that you
        // use to make the sound.
        announceNumber(nextIterationNumber);
      }else{
        announceNumber(input);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Neeraj! I'm still confused though. I don't really understand where abouts in my code this should go?

Comment: I think I'm missing something, put it where. Sorry, I'm really new to this.

Comment: Sorry I edited it there but the comment did not get saved.

    int n = Integer.parseInt(readNumberTV.getText().toString());
    announceNumber(n);

For the first time announceNumber has to be called explicitly but the next times would be called recursively.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain Neeraj, I'm not really getting this. Should this code go before my first switch and allows me to call on the on something for my second?

Comment: Hmm..I would explain what I have written above more. But on second thoughts, I think you may not be aware that android is having a text to speech conversion library.
If you don't want to have something specific, you can just go ahead and use it. I just created a demo project and the library worked flawlessly.
Please use the code here-
https://github.com/shklnrj/NumberReader/blob/master/src/com/subltecreation/numberreader/MainActivity.java
Let me know if the text-to-speech conversion library is not useful for you and I would explain the code that I suggested.

Comment: Neeraj, I finally got round to sorting out the text to speech thing and it works like a charm. Thanks mate; if I could one up you I would!